# Do Story rewards have to be narratively tied to the Story?

Tags: 7th-sea-2e

In 7th Sea, it doesn't seem to state whether story rewards have to be tied to the goal or story in some way or not. It would seem to me that they should be, so that part of the story is providing a reason for the improvement. However if it is not a requirement it provides a bit more flexibility when presenting the narrative because you don't have to work to provide an explicit link.

So is there anything that explicitly says Rewards need to tied to the Story narratively? An example. Player A has the story, Get Revenge for Murder of my Father. Goal, find and kill whose responsible. For a reward he wants Barterer which in no way seems tied to the story. Are there any rules either preventing this or demanding that it come up in the story somewhere, perhaps as a step?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the Developer of Stories for 7th Sea: Second Edition. I intentionally didn't answer that question when writing Stories because I feel that decision is something each group should be allowed to make on their own.

Personally, I wouldn't allow my players to make Rewards that weren't tied to their Stories. It's too much of a narrative break for my tastes.

Comment: I think this answer would be improved by a similar coda to the one you put on your sorcery-answer, identifying yourself as the designer of the feature in question.

Answer (score 2):

The rules don't really spell it out.

All of the example stories in the hero stories section tie their reward to *some* aspect of the story (either they come up in the steps, or are a result of the goal).

They also give a couple of examples of special hero stories where the reward has an impact on the story (Dracheneisen Seeker in the Die Kreusritter section; Redemption in the Corruption section).

But the rules themselves talk very loosely about the relationship between the goal, the steps of the story, and the reward.

**Here's how I'd do it:**

- For hero stories, the reward must be either a consequence of the goal, or it must be important to one of the steps of the story (preferably an important step).
- For GM stories, the hero can pick anything that satisfies the cost of the story.

For your character, I'd have them do one of the following:

- Include a step in the story where Barter is critical to the outcome (bargaining for information on the killer; bargaining with authorities to withdraw protection; etc.).
- Take the advantage as a reward for a GM story.
- Hold off on taking the advantage until the hero's completed his first story, and write a story specific to it.
- Take the Foul Weather Jack advantage, and work multiple stories at once.

Answer (score 0):

The character's story is there for two reasons: First, it is the mechanic that replaces experience points.  Second: It allows you some control over the plot and the ability to put your character in the direction you would like, regardless of how the plot goes.  However, you should definitely clear it with your GM since they need to know what minor arcs they need to include in the major one.  After all, it can be a bit stressful if you insist on your character's Story taking place in Avalon when the party is in Ussura.

The advantage to them only asking for a prompt, is that it leaves 99% of the story open to interpretation.  I've had a DM that narrated small "cut scenes" to show something the characters had no effect on, but contributed to their story.  If your GM is especially creative, and quite possibly if you work with them it can be rewarding.  For example, the GM could do a little piece about how the murderer increases some of his influence while you're helping get Lord Pompadour's cat out of a tree.  You learn something about making deals by the way Lord Pompadour hires you for a menial task, but the story advances.

Comment: Informative but that doesn't really answer the question. I added an example, to make it clearer that I'm asking specifically how goals tie to the story narratively.